# Django using prefetch_related to reduce queries

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to understand how I can improve the following query:

```
class PDFUploadRequestViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    def get_queryset(self):
        project_id = self.request.META.get('HTTP_PROJECT_ID', None)
        if project_id:
            return PDFUploadRequest.objects.filter(project_id=project_id)
        else:
            return PDFUploadRequest.objects.all()

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == 'list':
            return PDFUploadRequestListSerializer
        else:
            return self.serializer_class
```

The issue is that the more `PDFPageImage` objects are in the DB then it creates separate query for each of them thus slowing down the request. If there is only one value if `PDFPageImage` related to given `PDFUploadRequest` then its pretty fast, but for each additional value it is producing extra query and after doing some research I found out that `prefetch_related` might somehow help with this, but I have not been able to figure out how to use it with my models.

This is how the model for PDFUploadRequest looks like:

```
class PDFUploadRequest(models.Model, BaseStatusClass):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='uploaded_pdf')
    file_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=50,
        choices=BaseStatusClass.PDF_STATUS_CHOICES,
        default=BaseStatusClass.UPLOADED,
    )
    completed = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    processing_started = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    text = models.TextField(default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='pdf_requests', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, default=None)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name='pdf_requests', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, default=None)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created']
    def no_of_pages(self):
        return self.pdf_page_images.count()
    def time_taken(self):
        if self.completed and self.processing_started:
            return self.completed - self.processing_started
```

And this is the related model that I think is causing issues:

```
class PDFPageImage(models.Model, BaseStatusClass):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    pdf_request = models.ForeignKey(PDFUploadRequest, related_name="pdf_page_images", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField()
    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=50,
        choices=BaseStatusClass.PDF_STATUS_CHOICES,
        default=BaseStatusClass.UPLOADED,
    )
    page_number = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
   
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['page_number']
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['pdf_request', 'page_number'],
                                    condition=models.Q(deleted=False),
                                    name='pdf_request_and_page_number_unique')
        ]
```

Here is the serializer:

```
class PDFUploadRequestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    pdf_page_images = PDFPageImageSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)


    class Meta:
        model = PDFUploadRequest
        fields = ('id', 'file','file_name', 'status', 'pdf_page_images',
                  , 'owner', 'project')
        read_only_fields = ('file_name', 'pdf_page_images', 'text',
                           'owner', 'project')
```

I have tried using `prefetch_related` on the PDFPageImage model:

```
PDFUploadRequest.objects.filter(project_id=project_id).prefetch_related("pdf_page_images")
```

But I dont think it is doing anything. Any idea what can I do to reduce the query times here?

Comment: Where did you put prefetech related code? In the view I mean

Comment: You should also add `select_related("owner", "project")` as they point to foreign tables.

Comment: @ruddra it would be in the Viewset in the get_queryset() method, for the API endpoint. Is that what you are asking for?

Comment: Where are you seeing that there are multiple queries?

Comment: @aaron when I run app in DEBUG mode it shows in terminal

Comment: I couldn't reproduce that. Are you sure `project_id` is passed (truthy)? Or did you also replace the `else` block with `PDFUploadRequest.objects.all().prefetch_related("pdf_page_images")`? If you already did those, please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and/or a repro GitHub project.

Comment: Also edit your question to add what you see in the terminal.

Comment: @AlexT can you try the solution posted below and share the results.

Answer (score 0):

When a query is sent to the database it is better to try to get all the data needed in the future with that one (or few) queries. When you just retrieve the data of the object it will try to get additional data by extra queries which makes the server slow. For example, imagine we have a book with three authors (Notice that there is a many to many relationship between authors and books as a book can have multiple authors and an author can contribute to multiple books). When you get the book's data from the database it only gives you the primary keys of the authors. Imagine you want the name of the authors in the next processes. So django orm send a query to the database to get the data of the first author to get its author name. Then it wants the second author's name. So it hits the database another time. This goes for all of the related objects.

So, you have to optimize the query by prefetching all the authors' data that have contributed to the book with the book data. So for further data it does not need any other queries.

For your code I couldn't run it on my system becuase I don't know what is the implementation of the `BaseStatusClass` and the `PDFPageImageSerializer` serializer. So I tried to read your code. I believe that you have to change your code like this:

```py
PDFUploadRequest.objects.prefetch_related('pdf_page_images').filter(project_id=project_id)
```

and also:

```py
PDFUploadRequest.objects.prefetch_related('pdf_page_images').all()
```

Also try to omit the if condition in the `get_queryset` method. See if django will optimize the query by only having one query. I know the functionality needs two queries with a condition but try this to see if it helps you understand the problem. Also, know that `prefetch_related` can be used with a `Prefetch` class to send a query to it. Like this:

```py
Book.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('comments', Comment.objects.select_related('author').all()))
```

If you provide the whole code I would run it to find the optimized solution.